# Run AA 24/7 to process records from a DB (there is a new record every minute)

Tags: automation, rpa, automationanywhere

Looking for best practices here. I need to run AA on all days of the week from 08:00 am for 12 hours. Bot will look for new records in a SQL DB every minute. If there's a new record, it will process it (open a website, fill a form etc). Then it will check again if there's a new record and it will repeat the process.

The idea is to schedule a task to start the bot 8:00 AM. Once task starts bot will query SQL etc, but I need to keep the bot running looking for new records.

For now I am first opening the website where records will be inserted and will keep on looping (to check new records in the DB) as long as the website is opened,but I am sure there are more elegant ways to do this.

Looking forward your comments.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I would like to ask you the SLA for each database refresh. Do you want the web activity to be performed on real-time, or can it wait for some time (like checking every hour or so, and processing all new records)?

Because in your approach I believe there would be continuous DB hits even when there's no new record for a long time, which is not the best of approaches.

An alternative that I would like to suggest is to use some kind of a Message Queue which will monitor the database. Then you can write a listener for this Queue and as soon as there's a new record, your bot can process it.

Let me know your thoughts.

Regards,
Atharva

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We're doing UAT with 10 people and we expect new records every 10 minutes, but once this is deployed, it will be used by 50 people at least, and we would expect new records in the database every 1-2 minutes. I agree with you that querying the database when there are no records is not the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think one shortcoming in your approach is that you're keeping your website open all long, even when there's no new record for hours. I agree with what Atharva suggested above, you should only login to website when the operation needs to be performed.

Instead of running AA 27/7, you can write a service or something that will monitor the DB. And when there's a new record, will trigger your AA task in some way.